# Worklight loads both common and custom skin folder?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I develop a web using Worklight and have been creating skin for Android tablet, called `android.skin`.

However, when I test on tablet html on both simulator and console, it correctly loads the html, but it loads js file from both folder (`common` and `android.skin`).

How to load only from `android.skin` when I run on tablet?

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div style="width:300px">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="login" class="fullWidth">Log In</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/theJs.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</div>
```

**theJs.js** in **`common`** folder:

```
$('#login').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    alert('Common!');

    jq.mobile.changePage("nextPage.html", { transition: animation, changeHash: true });
});
```

**theJs.js** in **`android.skin`** folder:

```
$('#login').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    alert('Android.skin!');

    jq.mobile.changePage("nextPage.html", { transition: animation, changeHash: true });
});
```

**nextPage.html**:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <script src="js/nextPage.js"></script>
</div>
```

The result when I execute my app, both alert in `common` and `android.skin` folder are popped up. What I want is, because I want to design some different layout in tablet, so the content on html, js, and css must be different too.

**UPDATE:**

It seems it doesn't only load the code from both .js file, but also .css file.

Comment: Can you edit your question and describe the actual problem? Do you mean that when running the app, code from both the default skin and the tablet skin gets executed? The code snippets are w/out context to the problem, so they are not helpful.

Comment: Hi Idan :) Sorry if it's not descriptive, I have edited my question, pls kindly look at it again :)

Comment: Doesn't help. What is the **problem**? Is something not working as you expect, or is this just a phenomena you see (code from both default and the skin existing in the skin)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tablet skin you have added to the environment is dependent on the default "skin" of that same environment.

When loading a skin, it also contains the web resources of the default skin, so the CSS and JS of both the default skin and the tablet skin exist together, but only the code of the tablet skin is being used (where required).

This is explained in the [skins training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_03_Supporting_multiple_form_factors_using_Worklight_skins.pdf).

Do you see a different phenomena?

Comment: Hi Idan, from your answer, I just realized that actually in `application-descriptor.xml`, Worklight automatically puts the `common` and `android` folder in my new skin xml tag. When I try to remove the `common` folder, it doesn't any longer call the javascript from `common` folder. Thanks once again Idan for your support!!